# Confusing p values with ANOVA on a big dataframe

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to analyse the significant differences between different car company performance values across different countries. I am using ANOVA to do this.

Running ANOVA on my real dataset (30 countries, 1000 car companies and 90000 measurement scores) gave every car a zero p-value.

Confused by this, I created a reproducible example (below) with 30 groups, 3 car companies, 90000 random scores. Purposely, I kept a score of 1 for the Benz company where you shouldn't see any difference between countries. After running anova, I see a pvalue of 0.46 instead of 1.

Does any one know why is this ?

Reproducible example

```
set.seed(100000)
qqq <- 90000

df = data.frame(id = c(1:90000), country = c(rep("usa",3000), rep("usb",3000), rep("usc",3000), rep("usd",3000), rep("use",3000), rep("usf",3000), rep("usg",3000), rep("ush",3000), rep("usi",3000), rep("usj",3000), rep("usk",3000), rep("usl",3000), rep("usm",3000), rep("usn",3000), rep("uso",3000), rep("usp",3000), rep("usq",3000), rep("usr",3000), rep("uss",3000), rep("ust",3000), rep("usu",3000), rep("usv",3000), rep("usw",3000), rep("usx",3000), rep("usy",3000), rep("usz",3000), rep("usaa",3000), rep("usab",3000), rep("usac",3000), rep("usad",3000)), tesla=runif(90000), bmw=runif(90000), benz=rep(1, each=qqq))

str(df)
out<-data.frame()

for(j in 3:ncol(df)){
amod2 <- aov(df[,j]~df$country)
out[(j-2),1]<-colnames(df)[j]
out[(j-2),2]<-summary(amod2, test = adjusted("bonferroni"))[[1]][[1,"Pr(>F)"]]
}

colnames(out)<-c("cars","pvalue")
write.table(out,"df.output")
```

df.output

```
"cars" "pvalue"
"1" "tesla" 0.245931589754359
"2" "bmw" 0.382730335188437
"3" "benz" 0.465083026215268
```

Comment: This is a good question, answers may have to do with numerical inaccuracies. Try `aov(response~country-1)` ... ?

Comment: Are p-values exactly zero or very close to zero? How do the other ANOVA stats look?

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the "benz" p-value in your reproducible example: an ANOVA analysis requires positive variance (i.e., non-constant data).  If you violate this assumption, the model is degenerate.  Technically, the p-value is based on an F-statistic whose value is a normalized ratio of the variance attributable to the "country" effect (for "benz" in your example, zero) divided by the total variance (for "benz" in your example, zero), so your F-statistic has "value" `0/0` or `NaN`.

Because of the approach R takes to calculating the F-statistic (using a QR matrix decomposition to improve numerical stability in "nearly" degenerate cases), it calculates an F-statistic equal to 1 (w/ 29 and 89970 degrees of freedom).  This gives a p-value of:

```
> pf(1, 29, 89970, lower=FALSE)
[1] 0.465083
>
```

but it is, of course, largely meaningless.

With respect to your original problem, with large datasets relatively small effects will yield very small p-values.  For example, if you add the following after your `df` definition above to introduce a difference in country `usa`:

```
df = within(df, {
    o = country=="usa"
    tesla[o] = tesla[o] + .1
    bmw[o] = bmw[o] + .1
    benz[o] = benz[o] + .1
    rm(o)
})
```

you will find that `out` looks like this:

```
> out
   cars       pvalue
1 tesla 9.922166e-74
2   bmw 5.143542e-74
3  benz 0.000000e+00
>
```

Is this what you're seeing, or are you seeing all of them exactly zero?

Comment: No still there is no difference. I still get zero p values. However I noticed that when I select the cars that belong to few groups (for example 4) instead of 30, I get p values like this `"1" "tesla" 5.32623480765925e-121
"2" "bmw" 5.75987108013489e-146
"3" "benz" 1.62233501967656e-101
`

Comment: Well, with such a big dataset, it doesn't take *that* big a real difference to force all the p-value to exactly zero.  If you change my `0.1` offsets to `1` in the example above, all p-value will be zero.  At this point, my best guess is that the actual p-values are less than `1e-323` or so and can't be represented as non-zero with double-precision floating point.  Can you add the means and standard deviations of the `tesla` column by country to your question (e.g., using `with(df, tapply(tesla, country, mean, na.rm=TRUE))` and `with(df, tapply(tesla, country, sd, na.rm=TRUE))`)?